# Unable to unprotect message.State with only one OIDC provider in .NET Core Identity service

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, adfs

We are seeing the "unable to unprotect message.State" error when attempting to process an authentication against an Active Directory Federated Services (ADFS) host as it's OIDC provider. I've seen a couple other posts about this issue, but none of the other examples or answers match the specific case we are seeing.

Making our situation perhaps even more unusual, the problem is not appearing in all cases. Most users seem to have no problem processing their log-in and getting a successful redirect back to the application of origin.

The set-up is such that we have a central identity provision service that a couple different applications use, and that service, in turn, processes requests against our ADFS host. The relevant portions of our startup in the identity provision service look like this:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("adfs", "[Name of our Organization]", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        options.MetadataAddress = "https://[our-adfs-host/adfs]/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        options.Authority = "https://[our-adfs-host]";
        options.ClientId = "[our-client-id]"
        options.ClientSecret = "[our-client-secret]"; 
        options.ResponseType = "id_token";
        options.CallbackPath = "signin-oidc";
        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/LoggedOut/[name of application]";
    });
```

I think I'd be less stumped if the errors were occurring for all log-in challenges, but that's not the case -- most process successfully.

I'm not even necessarily expecting a definitive answer, here, just looking for the spark that might get me looking at the problem in the right way to find the answer.

Comment: Doyou have multiple instances of the client application?

Comment: @ToreNestenius, thanks for the question. I'll try to clarify. We have one instance of this client running, and it accesses only one OIDC authority -- our ADFS. We do, however, have a couple different applications which, in turn, use the authentication client. So in other words: [multiple web apps] -> [1 OIDC client] -> [1 ADFS-based OIDC Authority]. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Often when you have state problems is that the instance issuing the initial authentication request is not the same as the one who receives the final request with the authorization code.